# pyrocms professional: adding a new first uri segment?

Tags: codeigniter, uri, pyrocms

I want to use `thisdomain.com` for say a review site where each `company` has a set of sub pages... about, info, and related reviews.. and where we use the blog module to manage the review/posts.

Basically, I want the url structure to be as such,

`thisdomain.com/[company]/[blog|pages|etc]`

and also maintain core site pages for thisdomain.com,

`thisdomain.com/[blog|pages|etc]`

My first thought was to add an if statement to the system `config/routes.php` file and route all requests for `thisdomain.com` first to a module to db check if we have a company that fits  otherwise send it back to the default `pages` controller. But I haven't gone far enough down the rabbit hole to know if this is a lame concept.

Has anyone done this? Ideas? Is this retarded? Phil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't have thought this was possible. The issue here is that even if you route it through then CodeIgniter will not continue to trickle down through the remaining routes, which means your one global company route would break every other route in the system.

You can just do this sub-pages and use the blog plugin to get a list of pages based on a certain tag or category. /foo/blog would just be a page, and you call up the "foo" tag. Then link to your own /foo/blog/article/slug where slug is used to call the blog plugin again.

The module output is generally there to give you a default interface, but you can ignore them if you like.

Comment: Nice. Much less heartburn with this solution. Sometimes I still like to bang my head. Thanks.